# Why does get_post_status display published when attachment is in trash?

Tags: post-status

Is there a reason why using get_post_status() on an attachment page returns 'published' when the media item is actually in the trash?

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug or if not how to display the status of the attachment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The post status for attachments is `inherit`. You get the status for the parent post, not the real status. And that is probably still published.